# Fedora-21 epel-release conflict with nginx

Tags: nginx, fedora, epel

When installing nginx on Fedora-21 machine, i got following error:

Command:

> sudo yum install nginx`

Error: (showing only last few lines)

```
--> Processing Dependency: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.16.3) for package: 1:nginx-1.6.3-6.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libperl.so()(64bit) for package: 1:nginx-1.6.3-6.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.2()(64bit) for package: 1:nginx-1.6.3-6.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution Error: Package: 1:nginx-1.6.3-6.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libperl.so()(64bit) Error: Package: 1:nginx-1.6.3-6.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: libgd.so.2()(64bit) Error: Package: 1:nginx-1.6.3-6.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_5.16.3)  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

After doing some experiments, i identified that the issue was due to installation of epel-release package. So for turn around, i had to uninstall epel package (using yum remove epel-release). Upon removing that package, nginx installation went all fine, and then i had to reinstall epel-release package.
I was wondering if there is some other better alternative to work this out?

Comment: Are you building from source? I can see nginx-1.6.3 which is an older version. Is that intentional?

Comment: I am just using the command "sudo yum install nginx", with no other relevant commands before. I guess that would be downloading from the Fedora Repository only.

Comment: Please try yum update followed with yum install nginx and let me know if you still get the error.

Comment: Tried this several times already, Yum updates and then install nginx. Same error.

Comment: Have you tried building from source instead?

Comment: No, since i already got the working stuff, i din't gave that a try. But yes, that is worth a try. Thanks.

Comment: you should not be using EPEL repo with Fedora; EPEL is a repo with packages build from Fedora infrastructure targeted to RedHat EL, centos and derivates (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux). Whatever package you may find in EPEL, will already be present in Fedora repo.